# Query does not return a decimal answer for simple equation for percentage

Tags: teradata

I have a problem in Teradata (I belive) where I am trying to get a percentage of a remaining number. Teradata is not returning decimals

For example.

```
Call Center:
Number of Calls Offered: 1055
Number of Calls Handled: 1034
Calls Abandoned: 21 ** 1055-1034=21 **
Rate of Abandon: 2% ** (1055-1034)/1055 = 0.0199052132701422 **

select (NCO-NCH)/NCO from TABLE
```

It is rounding in this case to 0. I have tried multiple ways to pull the data and always no decimal. Is this only a problem with my companies Teradata platform or is this common?

Comment: That did work ... The are columns set to DECIMAL(4,0) and I was trying to CAST all of the variables ... but that seemed to make matters worse... just casting one was the answer... and it didn't seem to matter which one it was.

Answer (score 2):

Those columns are probably defined as INTEGERs resulting in an INTEGER, too.

You need to CASTat least one of the columns  to a DECIMAL of FLOAT or NUMBER (TD14):

select (NCO-NCH)/CAST(NCO AS DECIMAL(7,4)) from TABLE